# Finding Regex Pattern to Match on Last Names

Tags: python, regex

I need to match on the last name of a person in order to parse the value into my data table. For most cases it works, however some instances are not matching as expected. What needs to be changed to get my desired matches?

This is the current code snippet that I am using to test my pattern.

```py
pattern = re.compile(r'(?i)\w+\'\w+|\w+\-\w+|^(?:saint)+?(?:st)+?(?:DA)+?(?:DE LA)+?(?:DE las)+?(?:DE LOS)+?(?:DE)+?(?:DEL)+?(?:DI)+?(?:DU)+?(?:LA)+?(?:MAC)+?(?:MC)+?(?:SANTA)+?(?:SAN)+?(?:STE)+?(?:VANDER)+?(?:VAN DER)+?(?:VAN)+?(?:VON)+?\s?[a-z\'\-\,\.]+?[a-zA-Z\'.,\-]+(?!MRS)(?!\bJR\b)(?!\bSR\b)(?!\bII\b)(?!\bIII\b)(?!\bIV\b)(?!\bMR\b)(?!\bMRS\b)(?!\bMS\b)|^[a-z]{1,3}\s?[a-z\'\-\,\.]+|^\w+?')
text = "Van Der White"
result = pattern.search(text)
try:
    print(result.group())
except:
    print(result)
```

While this pattern will match on most cases such as

```py
"La Grone"
"Mac Millan"
"Del Rio"
```

It fails to match on cases such as these.

```py
"Van Der White"
"De La Rosa"
"Saint Cloud"
```

From my data table names follow the format Suffix Last First Prefix, and sometimes have multiple people in the string I am using my pattern on hence my decision to use regex instead of string splits since I do not always know how many names will be present on the current string I am working with.

Comment: Are you sure that you need regular expressions there?

Comment: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: `surname = name[name.rindex(" ") + 1:]`

Comment: Unless I misunderstood what you're trying to do, I highly doubt you'll be able to do that with RegEx, in a reliable manner. Even with all our "human processing power", it's sometimes tricky to know which part of a name is a last name. That being said, if you have a very finite number of entries, you could modify your regex to eventually match all of them, that would make sense were you to need to match, over and over, the same few names, but otherwise, you might be better out figuring a way to match the vast majority of your entries and do the last few ones by hand.